# JavaScript with IE6

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a input button with `onclick` event:

```
<input id="bSave" type="button" name="bSave" value=Save 
          onclick="save();window.close();">
```

Here is the save function:

```
function save(){
              //do some calculation
    calculate();
    //submit a form in this popup window
    document.RCSARiskAssessDimenResultForm.submit();
              //call parent opener to submit another form in parent window
    window.opener.document.RiskControlAssessmentDetailForm.bSave.onclick();
}
```

In my PC with Win7/IE8 , the submission request is sent and finished, there's no problem.
But the client environment with XP/IE6, sometimes(not always) the first submission just wasn't sent.
Seems that `window.close()` is called or other unknown reason (network delay?).

Any kind of suggestion (information) will be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

You should put your `window.close()` when you are sure your submits are done. Usually in form of a callbacks. This way you are in control of what happens.

Javascript has a single thread and it may look sequential but it is not. If your submits have a call to a server, or use a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` you start to have some asynchronous actions and the next JS statement is called.

May as IE6 has a more fragile implementation that takes some more time to do something and reveal a problem that you could have as well with other browsers with a slow connection.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a callback function for this.

See the following example.

```
function celebrate(){
    //your celebrate code here
}


function run(){
    //your run code here
}

function compete(){
    run();
    celebrate();
}
```

In the above case you will sometimes see that the celebrate would be called before or after the run function due to the nature of the javascript runtime.

Celebrating while running is a fail.

```
function run(callbackFunction){
    //your run code here

    //execute the callback
    callbackFunction();
}

function celebrate(){
    //your celebrate code here
}

function compete(){
    run(function(){celebrate();});
}
```

This makes sure you don't celebrate while running.

Cheers.

Comment: `new function(){celebrate();}` returns an object not a function. Just pass `celebrate` in

Comment: @bhagyas you can just pass `celebrate` no need to wrap it in a function

Comment: Wrapping it in a function gives the ability to pass more functions for the callback. :)

Comment: @bhagyas why don't you call more functions in celebrate!

Comment: `celebrate` is assumed to be an atomic function - where it only does one task. :)